# My API endpoint is not returning the expected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api, express

I have written a backend app with Express JS to retrieve info from a database through GET requests from an API endpoint. The query that I have used to GET from API endpoint is working in the Database , but I could not fetch the same details in a Web Browser as Response using Express JS. Tried my best to find out the issue, but I couldn't.

I tried to check whether I had a problem with my query, but the query is fetching the correct details, but I couldn't get any response in the web browser.

Here is my code where I think I had a bug :

```
      const { rows } = await pool.query(
                'SELECT  branches.ifsc, branches.bank_id, branches.branch, branches.address, branches.city, branches.district, branches.state FROM branches WHERE branches.branch LIKE $1% LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3' ,

        [q, limit, offset]
      );

      res.send(rows[0]);
    });
```

SQL Query used to Fetch Details:

```
    SELECT branches.ifsc, branches.bank_id, branches.branch, branches.address, branches.city, branches.district, branches.state FROM branches WHERE branches.branch LIKE '%RTGS%' ORDER BY branches.ifsc LIMIT 3;
```

Error Log:

```
Server is running on 7000
(node:19484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: syntax error at or near "LIMIT"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/kiddo/Desktop/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:604:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/kiddo/Desktop/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:401:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/kiddo/Desktop/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:200:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:294:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:275:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:210:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17)
(node:19484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19484) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: hey, what's the response you get ? you could try to add console.log(rows); to see what's inside your results

Comment: I am not getting any response from the server. It is an empty array

Comment: What does `console.log(rows)` right after your query show?  And what  does `console.log(rows[0])` right before your `res.send(rows[0])` show?  And, you should add a `try/catch` around your `await` so you can catch and log errors and at least do `res.sendStatus(500)` when you get an error.  What version of Express are you running?

Comment: It returning 'undefined' and a empty array '  []  '

Comment: What I need is an API endpoint that fetches the details as same as the above query I have used.  Please do give some hints to do that ?

Comment: What exactly is `undefined`?  It can't be that `console.log(rows)` shows `undefined`, but `console.log(rows[0])` is an empty array.  That's not possible.  You need to be more specific when providing us information.  I asked you for two pieces of information in my previous comment and still don't know the answer to either of them.

Comment: OK, so your `const { rows } = await pool.query(...)` is throwing an exception and you are not getting a query result.  Hopefully someone who knows your database can help you figure out why.  You also need `try/catch` around the `await` statement so you are handling your own errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect using `$1%` is causing issues in your sql statement. Try the following instead.

```
const { rows } = await pool.query(
        'SELECT  branches.ifsc, branches.bank_id, branches.branch, branches.address, branches.city, branches.district, branches.state FROM branches WHERE branches.branch LIKE $1 LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3' ,
['%'+q+'%', limit, offset]);
```

Comment: Thanks Maddy . This small thing  <   '%'+q+'%'  >  messed up my entire day. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sravan.k if this answer helped you, please accept this answer so that anyone else can make to it directly in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try With Callback function.

```
con.query("YOUR SQL QUERY HERE", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
```

parameter substitution Example

```
     var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = ? AND field2 >= ?";
connection.query(sql, [value1, value2], function(err, result, fields) {
    //do your operations HERE
    console.log(result);

});
```